# Your answer will be considered as correct if it has an absolute or relative error less than 10^(−6)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

In many Programming Problems, the above mentioned constraint is mentioned.
I have seem this in codechef as well as SPOJ.

E.g. [Link-1](http://www.codechef.com/JAN13/problems/ANDOOR) , [Link-2](http://www.codechef.com/problems/PARCOS) and many more. (See the section OUTPUT in these two sample links)

What is the meaning of this constraint ? And how can I ensure that this constraint is specified by my output ?

Comment: Do you know what the terms ["absolute error" and "relative error"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error) mean?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No, These terms are not very clear to me.

Comment: The "or" operator is the most important issue here. Moreover, what if one of the numbers is "0.0"? [I don't see this answered as of now.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolute error is:

```
|computedAnswer - correctAnswer|
```

Relative error is:

```
|(computedAnswer - correctAnswer) / correctAnswer|
```

Intuitively, absolute error is how far off the computed answer (or approximation) is from the correct (and possibly unknown) answer. Relative error is the ratio of the absolute error to the correct answer.

Thus, whether you are measuring the distance to the moon using a laser ranger or trying to place your left foot correctly during a fox-trot, your absolute error might be half a meter in either case. For the moon distance measurement, that would be pretty good; for the fox-trot, it would get you kicked off Dancing with the Stars.

Comment: But in programming problems, we actually don't know the correctAnswer in advance !!

Comment: @user1599964 But the poser of the problem knows the answer.

Comment: So suppose that I have computed the answer. Now what should I do to ensure that my answer satisfies this constraint ?

Comment: @user1599964: Code the program correctly and it should. If not, then the fault lies with the question, not your answer.

Comment: @user1599964 - For some mathematical calculations (e.g., singular value decomposition), you can actually determine bounds on the relative error (but not the absolute error) on a theoretical basis. For competitions like in your links, you can test your code with sample problems for which you know the correct answer.

Comment: Ok, but I guess then that in a problem, having this constraint makes sense only if EITHER calculated answer is near actual answer OR for hadling the truncating of a floating point result ?

Comment: @TedHopp Also, please tell that for satisfying this constraint, do i have to put a limit on number of digits after decimal. (Assuming the answer is a floating point number ) ?

Comment: @user1599964: You sumbit your code to the contest site.  If it computes results within the tolerance, then you will pass.  If not, then you will fail to pass!

Comment: @user1599964 - Note that if the correct answer is less than one, then the relative error is always larger than the absolute error. The constraints let you pass if either one is good enough. You will need to output _at least_ six significant digits to have a decent chance of the relative error being less than 10^-6. I would not limit the number of digits after the decimal; printing more cannot raise the error (unless the rounding error introduced by truncating the output happens to cancel your calculation error).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Ted Hopp said, a possibly important factor to reducing error is minimizing floating point drift/inaccuracies by:

- Reducing the total floating point calculations by simplifying/evaluating the set of operations that will work on your inputs. (e.g. simplifying the math expression as much as you can). This is because floating point errors compound over subsequent operations.
- Using the highest precision (e.g. double) for your calculations.
- Alternatively, you could make use of fraction-type or more numerically sound classes which you then evaluate to a floating point value right at the end.

Comment: Not necesarily. What you want to do is avoid substraction between similar values when computing. This is the principal case in which precision is lost.

Comment: @vonbrand Another case is addition of dissimilar magnitudes.

Comment: How so? Assume you have 6 significant digits to start with. Adding 100,000 and 1 gives 100,001 to 6 digits, but subtrating 100,000 from 100,002 gives 2 with 1 digit only. An example is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311382/solving-a-quadratic-equation-with-precision-when-using-floating-point-variables).

Comment: @vonbrand you will lose some precision from the trailing significant digits of the smaller number via truncation, depending on how many significant digits it and the larger number have.

Comment: No, the loss of precision in the _small_ number is of no significance (normally).

Comment: It is up to the problem domain to define what is meant by signficant or acceptable accuracy loss. There will be certain domains in which slight drift can result in problems, depending on how the values are used. Regardless, you are right that most operations are very accurate when observed in isolation, save for catastrophic cancellation (close subtraction). However, that does not mean that one can simply discard the other operations and treat them as a perfect "black box". Floating point numbers are in the end, a leaky abstraction; In some domains the leak is more pronounced than others.

Comment: @vonbrand a classical example is in any main game loop timer with high frequency updates. This involves incrementing an `elapsed_time` floating point value over the executable's run duration. After a few hours (depending on the simulation/tick rate) you can already start to see the effects of floating point drift. A similar problem in the MIM-104 Patriot missile system caused the death of 28 US soldiers on 25th Feb 1991 (the result of floating point drift over 100 hours caused timing to be thrown off by 0.34 seconds and its missile interception capabilities by at least half a kilometer).

Comment: @vonbrand - A simple experiment is to sum `1.0/x` where `x` goes from 1 up to 100 by 1, then summing `1.0/x` where `x` goes from 100 down to 1. You can also calculate the sum directly via a closed-form formula. Comparing the three values should demonstrate clearly the ill effects of adding dissimilar magnitudes (the first case).

Comment: @TedHopp, yes, you should do adding from smallest to largest.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple computer problem: evaluate 1/3.

If you use "normal" computer numbers such as floating point, double precision etc then your calculated version of 1/3 will not be 0.3333...., it will be 0.333333333332 or 0.333333333334 or something similar, as 1/3 cannot be exactly represented as either a floating point number or as a finite decimal expansion. It is certainly possible to evaluate 1/3 to within relative and absolute errors of 10^-6; both 0.333333333332 and 0.333333333334 meet this accuracy requirement.

So this requirement that answers only be accurate to within 10^-6 allows computer solutions using floats and double precisions for problems that don't have exact numerical solutions using only floats and double precision. Which in fact is almost all numeric problems - most fractions cannot be calculated exactly numerically; the computer uses approximations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem posers are saying that if:

```
sqrt((your_answer - their_answer)^2) < 1*10^-6
```

Then you are "correct"

It is very problematic to compare floating point values to be exact.  This is because of rounding in a limited precision machine (i.e. some math answers cannot be represented in a finite number of digits, such as 1.0/3.0).

Many solutions to problems performed on a computer are iterative.  This means, you start with a first guess, and calculate how much to change your guess.  You then repeat this, calculating how much to change your guess.  After you repeat this procedure, the amount you change your guess will get smaller and smaller (it will converge).  Once the change is smaller than some specified amount, you can consider your answer to have converged and you now have a "correct" answer.  Gradient decent algorithms are a classic example of this technique.  I haven't looked closely at the links provided, but perhaps to obtain the answer you need an iterative solution, which in this case you should use 1.0 * 10^-6 as your limit to test if your solution has converged.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent

It appears that the links to the site you posted are problems that would lend them self to numerical methods:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis

It seems like an interesting site with some challenging problems.